# How to place HTML tags in content from the_content()?

Tags: theme-development, themes, pages, the-content

Firstly, I am new to Wordpress so thank you for your patience.

I have a list of posts (with excerpts) being displayed in the page using Short Tags.

The output is fine , However, I wish to add and change some tags which is coming as a content from the_content as I see under page.php file of my theme files.

Any direction / guidance is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sorry to mark this as an answer for some reason I can't comment on this question.*

Can you explain more what you mean by "I have a list of posts (with excerpts) being displayed in the page using Short Tags."? Do you have a list of posts excerpts displayed on the front and some number of short tags in the backend that utilize some plugin?

Without more information I can only point you to the [content filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) on the WP Codex. You should be able to use that to filter the output before it is sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks @BFTrick . But, I figured out the solution. Clearing my question: I have a page which shows recent 5 posts. As in, I have used short tags for it. Now the solution which I was figured out was in posts.php of the theme file. That is where I define the_title() . I am marking your answer as correct, please edit it for others to refer to this comment :) Hope I was clear???